# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined. adding data to an array.

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angularjs

I'm just started learning AngularJS,I want to pass information from form then passing to controller and enter the information to an array but received this message "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined".I don't know with part did i do wrong.I hope you guys can help me solve this problem.Thank you in advance.

**form.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="formTraining">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formapp.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="UserController as usersCtrl">

    <h3>User Information</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="user in usersCtrl.mUsers">
        <p><ul>
            <li>{{user.name}}</li>
            <li>{{user.age}}</li>
            <li>{{user.occupation}}</li>
        </ul></p>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="FormController as formCtrl">

        <form name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && formCtrl.addUser(user)">
            <h5>Submit a Review</h5>

            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="UserCtrl.newUser.name"  class="form-control" placeholder="write your name.." title="Name">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="UserCtrl.newUser.age" class="form-control" placeholder="write you actual age.." title="Age">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="text" ng-model="UserCtrl.newUser.occupation"  class="form-control" placeholder="write your job.." title="occupation">
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="submit form">
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

**formapp.js**

```
(function(){


    var app = angular.module("formTraining",[]);



    app.controller('UserController',function(){

        this.mUsers = users;
    });

    app.controller('FormController',function(){
        this.newUser = {};

        this.addUser = function(user){
            user.push(this.newUser);
            this.newUser = {};
        };
    });


    var users = [{
        name:"michael",
        age:"27",
        occupation:"business"
    },{
        name:"john",
        age:"25",
        occupation:"police"
    }];

})();
```

Comment: `user` is indeed undefined. Sure, you pass it into `this.addUser`, but you never actually set it up as a variable. You probably meant `users`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you want `users`

```
    app.controller('FormController',function(){
        this.newUser = {};

        this.addUser = function(user){
            users.push(this.newUser);
                ^

            this.newUser = {};
        };
    });
```

Comment: appreciated your help sir.want more question.. is there any proper way to manipulate variable instead of direct access?

Comment: @khoi Maybe post another question on SO if you want to get the most answers to your new question.